# Making nice GIF from LiDAR point cloud with R ( using lidR package ?)

Tags: r, rgl, lidar, lidr

Could someone point me to some R code to make programmatically nice GIF from LiDAR point clouds like the rotating one in the vignette of the LidR package (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lidR/versions/3.0.3) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(lidR)
library(rgl)

LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)

exportPath = tempfile()

plot(las, bg = "white")
movie3d(spin3d(), duration = 5, movie = exportPath)
```

Check the documentation of `movie3d` and `spin3d` to control the speed and the number of frame.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing this